# Reduce width of WWW-Authenticate Box

Tags: php, basic-authentication

Just wanna ask about this php Basic access authentication, is there anyway to reduce the width or change the text "A username and password are being requested by `http://localhost`. The site says: "Local Site"".

Here's a sample : http://imageshack.us/a/img542/7557/auth.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot add design to that window. But you can change part of the text.

In the apache config (or .htaccess file), you have something like this:

```
<Location /secure>
AuthType basic
AuthName "private area"
AuthBasicProvider dbm
AuthDBMType SDBM
AuthDBMUserFile /www/etc/dbmpasswd
Require valid-user
</Location>
```

The AuthName directive is the part that says "local site" in your config. Here you can enter whatever you want to say to the user.

The hostname will change as soon the site is deployed and accessed via a real hostname.

Answer (score 0):

From PHP site **NO**.

Only way is to rebuild XUL in firefox.

> [Firefox install folder]\omni.ja\xul\chrome\toolkit\content\global\commonDialog.css
>
> [Firefox install folder]\omni.ja\xul\chrome\toolkit\content\global\commonDialog.xul